# Semáforo Arduino com PWM

Tags: arduino

Olá,

Criei um código Arduino para representar o funcionamento de um semáforo, entretanto também estou usando mesmo código para (ao mesmo tempo) enviar sinais de PWM para um outro dispositivo.

O código está funcionando, porém pude notar que o controle de acionamento das cores do semáforo não estão fluindo naturalmente como deveria.

Portanto gostaria de saber o que poderia ser feito para que resolver esse problema.

OBS.: Já tentei mudar o valor das variáveis `tempoVermelho`e `tempoVerde`, mas mesmo assim não consegui dar fluidez ao semáforo.

```
// Definição dos pinos de saída para os LEDs do semáforo
#define VERMELHO 10
#define AMARELO 9
#define VERDE 8

// Definindo um valor máximo para a repetição de cada procedimento no Loop
#define MAX_LOOP 40000

// Variavel responsável por realizar a contagem dos procedimentos realizados no Loop
int interacao = 0;

// Variáveis de controle do tempo gasto em cada cor do semáforo
int tempoVermelho = MAX_LOOP * 0.4;
int tempoVerde =  MAX_LOOP * 0.8;

void setup() {

  // Definição dos pinos dos LEDs como saídas digitais
  pinMode(VERMELHO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(AMARELO, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(VERDE, OUTPUT);

  // Inicialização da comunicação serial
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Chamando a função que altera o PWM
  pwmSetup(); 
}

void loop() {

  analogWrite(3, 34);
  analogWrite(11, map(analogRead(A1), 0, 1023, 0, 255));

  // Laço responsável por deixar o sinal fechado enquanto "interacao" for menor que a metade de "MAX_LOOP"
  if(interacao >= 0 && interacao < (tempoVermelho)){
    
    semaforoFecahdo();
    
  }
  
  // Laço responsável por deixar o sinal aberto enquanto "interacao" for menor que 75% de "MAX_LOOP"
  else if(interacao >= (tempoVermelho) && interacao < (tempoVerde)){
    
    semaforoAberto();
    
  }

  // Laço responsável por deixar o sinal fechado enquanto "interacao" for menor que "MAX_LOOP"
  else if(interacao >= (tempoVerde) && interacao < MAX_LOOP){
    
    semaforoAtencao();
    
  }

  // Incrementando o valor da variável "interacao"
  interacao++;

  // Condição responsável por zera a variável "interacao" quando a mesma atinge o valor da variável "MAX_LOOP"
  if(interacao == MAX_LOOP){
    interacao = 0;
  }
}

// Método chamado no Setup para definir o PWM para 31khz de frequência
void pwmSetup() {
  
  pinMode(3 , OUTPUT); //OCR2B 3 e 11 são pinos de PWM do Arduino
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); //OCR2A
  
  // Alterando os registradores para que a frequencia do PWM seja de 31250hz
  TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM20);
  TCCR2B = _BV(CS20);
  OCR2A = 0;
  OCR2B = 0;
  
}

// Métodos auxiliares para o controle de acionamento dos LEDs do semáforo
void semaforoFecahdo(){
  digitalWrite(VERMELHO, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(AMARELO, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(VERDE, LOW);
}

void semaforoAberto(){
  digitalWrite(VERMELHO, LOW);
  digitalWrite(AMARELO, LOW);  
  digitalWrite(VERDE, HIGH);
}

void semaforoAtencao(){
  digitalWrite(VERMELHO, LOW);
  digitalWrite(AMARELO, HIGH);  
  digitalWrite(VERDE, LOW);  
}
```

Comment: seria legal você citar se já fez alguma tentativa para resolver o problema. Isso ajuda na resposta da comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, o problema é que você ta contando chamadas da função loop. Elas não são em intervalos iguais pois o arduino faz uma série de coisas extras que podem atrasar a execução, e com isso dá a impressão que não ta "fluindo". Você precisa usar funções onde você pega os millisegundos/segundos/etc e usar eles como referencia na sua lógica.

No site oficial existe um [exemplo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay), mas existe um mais simples [aqui](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/using-millis-for-timing).

Answer (score 1):

Cara não sei se é interessante para você, mas existe um conceito de Thread, onde você pode executar "varias coisas ao mesmo tempo", na verdade você executar as coisas (threads) em espaços de tempo dando a impressão de acontecerem juntas! Assim por exemplo executa uma thread para controlar o semáforo e envia o PWM após cada mudança de cor.. ou um intervalo de tempo! Espero ter sido claro!

Segue um vídeo de um cara muito bom no assunto Ivan Seidel (ele criou uma biblioteca para isso)

Parte 1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeP_NiajWME

Parte 2 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SyutmiLzj0

Na descrição do vídeo tem o GitHub dele com o arquivo da biblioteca e o exemplo!

Espero ter ajudado! Um abraço!